# What's the measure of height relative to $BC$ in the triangle below?.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:In the isosceles triangle $ABC$ ($AB = BC$) is marked
the interior point O whose distances to sides $AB, BC and AC$ are $2, 3$ and $5$ respectively,
If the sum of the height measurements of triangle $ABC$ is $30$, calculate the
measure of height relative to $BC$.

My progress.. (drawing without scale)

[image]

I try :
$BF = h_1, CL = HK = h_2$

$HM \parallel FB \implies\\
\angle IMO \sim IBF:\\
\triangle AMH \sim ABF\\
\triangle OIM \sim \triangle AFB \implies\\
\frac{IM}{FB}=\frac{IO}{AH}=\frac{OM}{AB} \rightarrow \frac{IM}{h_1}=\frac{2}{AF}=\frac{OM}{AB}\\
\triangle ION \sim \triangle KCA \sim \triangle LAC$

but I can't finish...

Comment: What does "height relative to BC" mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  same $AK$

Comment: While we are not given the angles of triangle ABC, if you assume it to be equilateral, we can easily use [Viviani's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani's_theorem), and it still matches the given conditions.

Comment: @ACB  I didn't post the answer because I think it's not correct (AK=12.5) I think it's one of the other alternatives $7.5$ or $6.75$ .. I also couldn't make the drawing to scale. Segments 2, 3 and 5 are correct but the sum of the heights is giving 31, close to the 30 given and the height relative to the BC side is giving 7.07

Comment: @ACB   they don't make things easy  :) :)

Comment: @ACB  this question is on the subject of similarities so it should probably be used

Comment: @ACB I'll wait a while to see if anyone has any fancy ideas...

Comment: @ACB  I need to leave now .. later I'll take it easy

Comment: @ACB  Then see a similar problem I posted in the statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If altitude from $A$ and $C$ to the opposite sides is $h_1$ and from $B$, it is $h_2$, then

$2 h_1 + h_2 = 30 \tag1$

If $A$ is the area of $\triangle ABC$,

$ \displaystyle a = c = \frac{2A}{h_1}, b = \frac{2A}{h_2}$

Now note that $A = Area ~ \triangle OAB + Area ~ \triangle OBC + Area ~ \triangle OAC$

$ \displaystyle A = \frac{1}{2} \left[ 3 a + 2c + 5 b \right] = 5A \left(\frac{1}{h_1} + \frac{1}{h_2}\right) $

$ \implies \displaystyle \frac{1}{h_1} + \frac{1}{h_2} = \frac{1}{5} \tag2$

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$, can you solve for $h_1$?

Comment: One solution is for equilateral triangle.

Comment: @ACB yes that is absolutely correct.

Comment: perfect..$\frac{15}{2}$...it's correct..gratitude

Comment: $10$ would also be a solution..but if it were 10 we would have 3 equal heights and therefore an equilateral triangle

Comment: @petaarantes yes that is correct